# Airplane Rounded Body

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to make an airplane body from what was a square, and this is what I have so far:

[image: Plane 1]

I tried to added a `Subdivision Surface`, but that doesn't make it look right:

[image: Plane 2]

I have also tried to add a `Bevel`, but that doesn't look right either:

[image: Plane 3]

What is the best way to achieve a rounded body?

Comment: the best way is to start with a cylinder (or circle )

Comment: That is what I was going to do too, but I thought that I could just do a `Subdivision Surface`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, model the differences in the x dimension; the tail is never as thick as the fuselage. go into edit-mode and scale the faces of the tail on the x axis. (<kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) you may need to hit <kbd>O</kbd> to maintain a good profile while scaling.

Next go in and select the top and bottom side edges of the tail and in the options on the right (<kbd>N</kbd>) turn up the *Mean Crease* to 1.00. This will make sure that as the side is smoothed, the profile is not lost.

Based on your second screen shot, I would say that you have included the entire side of the fuselage as one N-Gon: you need quads for sub-surf to work efficiently. You can go in and break the large n-gon up by selecting opposing vertices and hitting <kbd>J</kbd>. Now you can successfully add a subdivision surface modifier without getting unexpected results.

I will add screen shot when i get home :) hold on; they're coming.